# Java EE7: @DatasourceDefinition, how to parameterize values?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa

I am learning how to use `@DataSourceDefinition`. The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/annotation/sql/DataSourceDefinition.html) gives a specific example as

```
 @DataSourceDefinition(name="java:global/MyApp/MyDataSource",
      className="com.foobar.MyDataSource",
      portNumber=6689,
      serverName="myserver.com",
      user="lance",
      password="secret"
   )
```

**Question**
How can I substitute these values for environment variables? like `DB_HOST`, `DB_URL`

The reason is when I deploy my application to providers like `OPENSHIFT`, all I get the values to use to connect to database.

I would not like to hardcode them in my codebase. This adds coupling to particular database and can not be switched at runtime

Any ideas?

Comment: Most of the servers provide its own way to define data sources, which decouples it from application. This definition could be used for testing, but I wouldn't recommend using it in any serious development.

Comment: Can you give me some examples of doing this?

Comment: Example of doing what?

Comment: "servers provide its own way to define data sources"

Comment: Just google your server name and data source. e.g Tomcat -http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html, WebSphere Liberty - http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/twlp_dep_configuring_ds.html?cp=SSAW57_8.5.5%2F3-3-11-0-3-3-14-0-0&lang=en, WebSphere Application Server - http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.iseries.doc/ae/tdat_tccrtprovds.html?cp=SSAW57_8.5.5%2F2-3-0-23-3-0-7&lang=en etc...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to deploy a Java EE application in OPENSHIFT as well as in your LOCAL JBoss then it's recommended to use the **JBoss configuration file** to configure the datasource properties and use that *datasouce JNDI name* in your *persistence.xml*.

Refer : https://help.openshift.com/hc/en-us/articles/202964690-Default-database-connectivity-configurations-for-JBoss-Applications

If you really *don't* want to use the application server (like JBoss) specific configurations. Then you can write a data source *wrapper* for **@DataSourceDefinition** annotated class and change the value from of the data source using a external property file.

Refer : http://jdevelopment.nl/switching-data-sources-datasourcedefinition