# How to use @DataSourceDefinition

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I'm intrigued by [`@DataSourceDefinition`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/annotations/2.0/apidocs/jakarta.annotation/jakarta/annotation/sql/datasourcedefinition) but I'm unsure how to use it due to the (plain text) password attribute. As [mentioned in the spec](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/annotations/2.0/annotations-spec-2.0.html#jakarta-annotation-sql-datasourcedefinition):

> Although the annotation allows you to specify a password, it is recommended not to embed passwords in production code. The password element in the annotation is provided as a convenience for ease of development.

From that I understand that it should only be used locally, but how would that work? Would one need to remove the annotation before building for a prod release? Such a philosophy is quite conflicting with several of [the twelve factors](https://12factor.net/): I (codebase checked into revision control), III (externalized configuration), X (dev/prod parity).

I'd love to see EL in these kinds of annotations in future Jakarta releases, but until then, could someone explain how to use `@DataSourceDefinition` in any other setting than a purely local toy example?

I'm aware of [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26064437/java-ee7-datasourcedefinition-how-to-parameterize-values), but if the answer is simply "use the mechanism of your application server", doesn't that render the annotation useless?

Answer (score 0):

Using a Payara server (the same in Glassfish) you can use password alias'es in definition: ${ALIAS=} that must be defined in server configuration

```
@DataSourceDefinition(name="java:global/ExampleDataSource",
  className="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource",
  user="${mysql.user}",
  password="${ALIAS=mysql-db-password}",
  databaseName="${ENV=MYSQL_DBNAME}",
  serverName="localhost"
```

)

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not really interested in a Payara/Glassfish-only solution. I think I may have  found something though: using the web.xml approach (instead of an annotation) and using maven's resource plugin with filtering, I might be able to put placeholders that maven can replace with property values (which I can provide from the command line)... Still, not great though.